# Mockito: populating different values on void methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am using Mockito for my unit tests. I need to mock a void method which populates some input.
**Very very naive Example:**

```
class Something {
   AnotherThing thing = new AnotherThing();
   public int doSomething(Stuff stuff)
   {
      thing.doThing(stuff);
      if(thing.getName().equals("yes")){
        return 1;
      }
      else {
        return 2;
      }
   }
}

class AnotherThing() {
   public void doThing(Stuff stuff){
       if(stuff.getName().equals("Tom")) {
          stuff.setName("yes");
       }
       else {
          stuff.setName("no");
       }
   }
}

class Stuff()
{
   String name;
   // name getters and setters here
}
```

In this instance I would be trying to to mock `AnotherThing` to test `Something`.

However, I call this void method multiple times in the class I am testing. I need different " `Answer`"s every time I call it. What I mean is, I want to invoke the void method to do different things every time it is called.

I looked through the API and could not find a solution for this. Is this even possible with Mockito?

Comment: I don't quite understand what's the meaning of "void method ... populate some input".

Comment: Your example code is still unclear: you declare `doThing()` as `void` but then you call `.equals()` as if it returns a value.

Comment: Thank you daniel. I wish I could specify my exact example but it is production code. I fixed this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is a Mockito `Answer` object.  This is an object that contains a wee bit of functionality that you can run when a method of a mock is called.  Check out the Mockito documentation of `doAnswer` for more detail; but basically what you want is something like this.

```
  doAnswer(new Answer<Object>(){
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
           Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
           Stuff argument = (Stuff) arguments[0];
           if(stuff.getName().equals("Tom")) {
              stuff.setName("yes");
           }
           else {
              stuff.setName("no");
           }
           return null;
        }
     }).when(mockObject).doThing(any(Stuff.class));
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that answers the question keeping the `void` return type. However, this is horribly verbose code so I'd favour refactoring the class under test if possible.

Comment: @Brad Yes, that's certainly the case.  I was just trying to illustrate the answer using the original poster's original code.  I kind of assumed that the original code was there for illustrative purposes, not because this was going to be in the poster's finished software.

Comment: +1 cause it solves the issue, though I was hoping for a more elegant way like when the method is not void, since usage of answer is discouraged by mockito's documentation

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "usage of answer is discouraged by mockito's documentation" please?  The Mockito team have put a lot of effort into Answers and related functionality.  I'm not sure why they would then go and discourage the use of that functionality.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [simpler way](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing()):

```
doNothing().doNothing().doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

In this way, multiple calls to the method can do different things.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito give you a possibility to stub a consecutive calls. I think this is what you need. Here is a link to necessary part in [mockito documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10).

You can write like this:

```
Mockito.when(mockAnotherThing.doThing(stuff)).thenReturn("yes").thenReturn("no");
```

After this mockito during first invocetion will return "yes" and during second - "no".

And by the way, I think you need to change your example code like this (in other case it will not work):

```
class AnotherThing() {
   public String doThing(Stuff stuff){
       if(stuff.getName().equals("Tom")) {
         return "yes";
       }
       else {
          return "no";
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, but my question is does it give the possibility to stub consecutive calls for void methods?

Comment: Ok. In such case, please, clarify what do you want exactly to do (may be post better example). Because I can't understand why do you need to mock void method and what do you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use equals as the return type is void either change the return type of doThing() to String and then mock like this

```
 Anotherthing anotherthing = mock(Anotherthing.class)
 when(anotherThing.doThing(isA(Stuff.class))).thenReturn("yes").thenReturn("no");
```

you might want to mock this multiple times else the last stubbed value ("no" is returned) after 2 consecutive calls;

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need different `Answer`? You could use the same one:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Object>(){
    private int call;
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
        ...
        call = call + 1;
        if (call % 2 == 0) {
        //do something
        } else {
        //another behavior 
        }
    }
 }).when(mockObject).doThing(any(Stuff.class));
```